# Convert CURL xquery Batch script to Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, curl, https, xquery

I am trying to transform a curl command on powershell.
I can not understand how to pass data "declare namespace" in the body.

Batch CURL Code :

```
@echo off
@for /F "usebackq delims=*" %%i IN (`@WHERE /R "C:\Program Files" curl`) DO @set CURL=%%i
@IF NOT DEFINED CURL echo [101;93m Enable to find CURL. Please verify installation in "C:\Program Files" (C:\Programmes) [0m && goto end
@echo curl found on ^<%CURL%^>

@echo Req XQuery  ...
@call "%CURL%"  -k  -u xxxx:xxxxx  -H "Content-Type: application/xquery" -d "declare namespace pncf = \"ns.innes.plugncast.frontals\";pncf:getDevicesWithStatus()"  --url "https://localhost/.db/frontalsdb" > return.xml

:END
@pause
```

My Powershell Invoke-WebRequest Code :

```
add-type @"
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    public class TrustAllCertsPolicy : ICertificatePolicy {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(
            ServicePoint srvPoint, X509Certificate certificate,
            WebRequest request, int certificateProblem) {
            return true;
        }
    }
"@
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::CertificatePolicy = New-Object TrustAllCertsPolicy

$user = "xxxx"
$pass = "xxxx"
$pair = "${user}:${pass}"
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair)
$base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $base64"


$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add('Authorization',$basicAuthValue)

$Body = @{
    "declare namespace pncf" = '"ns.innes.plugncast.frontals";pncf:getDevicesWithStatus()'
}

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://localhost/.db/frontalsdb" -Headers $headers -ContentType application/xquery -Body $Body -Method POST
```

The batch script retrieves XML and stores it in result.xml.
The powershell script returns:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors XPST0003 static core 1 25 1 26
Au caractère C:\test.ps1:29 : 11
+ $result = Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://localhost/.db/frontalsdb ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm - why not just call curl from PowerShell?